# Moment.js issue format method is not working Correctly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var a = moment("24 12 1995").format('DD MM YYYY');
alert(a)
```

// This should be valid but its not.

```
var a = moment("12 24 1995").format('DD MM YYYY');
alert(a)
```

// This should be Invalid, but its valid. (Month is 24)

**Version : Moment.js 2.10.3**

Comment: 24 months? Which planet are you on? Check formats http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: I deliberately write '24' to check if it gets Invalid. but its valid.

Comment: you will need to specify the input format as  2nd param. `moment('24 12 1995','DD MM YYYY')`

Answer (score 5):

You should pass the format as an argument:

```
moment("24 12 1995", "DD MM YYYY");
```

What `.format` function does is formatting the output.

So you can do:

```
var format = "DD MM YYYY";
var date = moment("24 12 1995", format);
alert(date.format(format));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the second parameter

```
moment("24 12 1995","DD MM YYYY");
```

to specify the format of the input string.

Then you can format it any way you want :

```
moment("24 12 1995","DD MM YYYY").format('MM DD YYYY')
moment("24 12 1995","DD MM YYYY").format('DD MM YYYY')
moment("24 12 1995","DD MM YYYY").format('ddd M YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
moment("24 12 1995").format('DD MM YYYY');
```

You're parsing `"24 12 1995"` using moment's default format options, then taking the created moment object, and outputting it in the `'DD MM YYYY'` format, effectively making your `a` variable a string.

What you want instead is the [string+format constructor of moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), which you use like this:

```
 moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```